# Howto scale down a sprite in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx, scaling

How can I smaller a sprite to the half size for example ?

With following code nothing changes regarding size. Providing a value > 1f will larger the Sprite. How can I smaller the sprite ?

```
geldSprite = TextureManager.getSprite("symbolsIcons/coin.png");
geldSprite.scale(0.5f);
geldSprite.draw(batch);
```

Comment: @Squiddie I'm interested, why are you suggesting to avoid sprite class?

Comment: Heh, I'm not using sprites at all actually. Working directly with textures, so I needed proper excuse for that. :)